# what is faster: one call to a function with many parameters or more calls to functions with fewer parameters?

Tags: performance, function, parameters, call

I have 9 buffers that I need to send over CAN. I have a function that has 9 parameters, representing the code for which variables I want to have in each buffer. The function contains 9 switch-case. The question is: will this be faster if I have 3 functions each with 3 parameters? So instead of calling one function with 9 parameters, it's faster to call 3 functions with 3 parameters?

Comment: It might be easier knowing which programming language / environment / calling conventions are relevant here.

Comment: and the processor is piccolo from TI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a tiny bit, but you probably loose more when you try to figure out which method to call.

Besides, the possible gain is several orders of magnitude less than IO (the CAN-bus) so you should focus on creating readable and correct code.